# BackgroundWorker limit number of workers and create them as become available

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a function that is creating a `BackgroundWorker` for each object in the list, what I want to do now is limit the number of workers created to 20, and as they finished, process the next item in the list. I was thinking on using a queue and before processing the worker check the queue size if it's <20 then create the worker and add it to the queue. My question is how can I remove that item from the queue once it's finished? and how can I set the loop to wait until a worker becomes available?

***EDIT***
I think I'm close and this is what I have now, but the problem is the program is getting stuck at the `while` loop:

```
var myObjectList = new List<myObject>();
myObjectList = PopulateList();
BackgroundWorker bgw;
foreach (var obj in myObjectList)
{
    bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    while(BgwList.Count >= 20); //getting stuck here, why?
    BgwList.Add(bgw);
    if(!bgw.IsBusy)
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync(obj);
    }
}
```

Removing the `BackgroundWorker` once it is finished:

```
void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    BgwList.Remove((BackgroundWorker)sender); //verified that bgw is being removed from list
    //... other code
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to manually limit the number of jobs being run in parallel? What is the bottleneck on these jobs?

Comment: @Jon the workers are firing off a web service and waiting for the response, the problem is that the account to use the web service is limited to 25 processes, if it goes over 25 then it crashes, so just to be safe I want to set the limit at 20.

Comment: OK. What about the `BackgroundWorker` choice? Do you specifically need to create them, or do you just want to do work in the thread pool and are open to other options?

Comment: @Jon I don't know if it's the only way, but `BackgroundWorker` was the easiest way to report progress in our application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly? Don't use `BackgroundWorker`. Use TPL manually, [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) or even [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) (Rx) if you want this kind of control.

Personally I would use TPL Dataflow and I would setup an `TransformBlock<MyObject, MyObject>` which you configure with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` that makes sense for you (e.g. you want to process 20 at a time) and then link that back to a UI updating `ActionBlock<MyObject>` that is configured to run on the UI (`Dispatcher`) thread. Such code would look something like this...

***Somewhere in your initialization logic, possibly as part of Window constructor (NOTE: must be executed on the main Dispatcher thread to work correctly)***

```
TransformBlock<MyObject, MyObject> myProcessingBlock = new ActionBlock<MyObject, MyObject>(
   myObject =>
   {
     // ... perform your processing of this object here ...

     return myObject;
   },
   new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
   {
      MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20
   });

ActionBlock<MyObject> myUINotificationBlock = new ActionBlock<MyObject>(
   myObject =>
   {
       // ... update the UI details for this data here ...
   },
   new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
   {
       TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() // must be executed on the Dispatcher block!
   });

 myProcessingBlock.LinkTo(myUINotificationBlock);
```

***And this is how you would post new work to it:***

```
MyObject someObjectToProcess = GetSomeObjectToProcess(...);

myProcessingBlock.Post(someObjectToProcess);
```

The rest is all handled for you by the magic of the TPL Dataflow Library. Just declare it and set it free. TPL Dataflow even supports `async` methods, so if you know you're going to be making web service calls you can just use the `async` keyword on the method you define for the `TransformBlock<MyObject, MyObject>` like so:

```
TransformBlock<MyObject, MyObject> myProcessingBlock = new ActionBlock<MyObject, MyObject>(
   async myObject =>
   {
     HttpClient someHttpClient = new HttpClient();

     HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await someHttpClient.PostAsync(..., ...);

     return myObject;
   },
   new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
   {
      MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20
   });
```

This way you won't even block a CPU thread while the HTTP network call is outstanding which is even more full of win.

Comment: I really like this solution. I've just started (yesterday) looking at TPL Dataflow, and I'm impressed with its expressiveness. Good answer.

Comment: @JimMischel I guarantee you will love it. Once you have the "aha" moment you'll wonder what you were doing wasting your time cobbling together these kinds of workflows yourself in the past. :) Has awesome integration with Rx too, so you can create Rx sources with TPL Dataflow doing the work under the covers. Enjoy!

Comment: @DrewMarsh This might be what we need, I will have to read more into it since I didn't know about until now.

Comment: @DrewMarsh just wanted to say that we ended up using TPL dataflow, and WOW it's perfect it's making me rethinking everything I've done now! thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear whether you want that loop to wait until all the objects have been processed, or if you want that loop to start the processing, queue the rest, and then continue while the workers do their processing.

I'm going to assume the second.

I'll say up front that there's probably a cleaner way to do this using async/await, but I'm not so good with those yet. But my proposal below will work.

First, create a `BlockingCollection<myObject>`. That's a shared queue that your workers will use.

Then, create 20 threads (either background worker or Task) that process the queue. Here's an example using just 2 background workers.

```
BlockingCollection<myObject> theQueue = new BlockingCollection<myObject>();
bgw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
bgw2 = new BackgroundWorker();
bgw1.RunWorkerAsync();
bgw2.RunWorkerAsync();

// now, populate the queue
foreach (var obj in myObjectList)
{
    theQueue.Add(obj);
}
// mark the queue as complete for adding.
// Which means that the background workers will know to exit if
// there are no more items in the queue. (i.e. they won't wait for more items)
theQueue.CompleteAdding();

// At this point, all the background workers are processing the queue
// and the main thread is free to continue.
// The background workers will all notify the completed event when they're done.
```

The RunWorkerAsync method for each worker reads the queue until it's empty, like this:

```
foreach (var obj in theQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    // process object
}
```

As I said, you can do the same thing with Tasks as well.

Another option is to start a single background task that makes asynchronous Web requests and limits the number of concurrent requests using a semaphore. Don't have an example for that one offhand.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Parallel.ForEach` in `System.Threading.Tasks`
This lets you pass in a collection of objects and spawn a new thread for each object in the collection.
The `ParallelOptions` has a few nifty settings including setting the max degree of parallelism.

```
var myObjectList = new List<myObject>();
myObjectList = PopulateList();
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20};
Parallel.ForEach(myObjectList, options,
         (myObject) =>
         {
              //Do Work
              //On Complete Fire an event
              if (UpdateProgressEvent != null)
              {
                     UpdateProgressEvent (null, new UpdateProgressEventArgs(Something));
              }
          });
```

You should have a look at passing in a loop state to stop the loop if you are wanting to have a user break the loop if it takes too long to execute.

Comment: The problem with Parallel::ForEach is that it doesn't understand async method bodies. It's intended to be used for compute only tasks. So if OP wanted to make async http calls, you would have to burn a CPU thread with a manual call to .Wait() or .Result or, perhaps worse, you wouldn't realize this and declare the equivalent of an async void method body which Parallel::ForEach would execute 20 at a time, but burn through all N in the queue as the CPU control would return the working TPL thread at the first await statement. Long story short, use Parallel::ForEach only for compute bound tasks.

Comment: Cheers for the explanation.